# Root to leaf algo bug

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, binary-tree

Wrote an unnecessarily complex solution to the following question:

> Given a binary tree and a sum, determine if the tree has a
>   root-to-leaf path such that adding up all the values along the path
>   equals the given sum.

Anyway, I'm trying to debug what went wrong here. I used a named tuple so that I can track both whether the number has been found and the running sum, but it looks like running sum is never incremented beyond zero. At any given leaf node, though, the running sum will be the leaf node's value, and in the next iteration the running sum should be incremented by the current running sum. Anyone know what's wrong with my "recursive leap of faith" here?

```
def root_to_leaf(target_sum, tree):
    NodeData = collections.namedtuple('NodeData', ['running_sum', 'num_found'])

    def root_to_leaf_helper(node, node_data):
        if not node:
            return NodeData(0, False)

        if node_data.num_found:
            return NodeData(target_sum, True)

        left_check = root_to_leaf_helper(node.left, node_data)
        if left_check.num_found:
            return NodeData(target_sum, True)

        right_check = root_to_leaf_helper(node.right, node_data)
        if right_check.num_found:
            return NodeData(target_sum, True)

        new_running_sum = node.val + node_data.running_sum 
        return NodeData(new_running_sum, new_running_sum == target_sum)

    return root_to_leaf_helper(tree, NodeData(0, False)).num_found
```

EDIT: I realize this is actually just checking if any path (not ending at leaf) has the correct value, but my question still stands on understanding why running sum isn't properly incremented.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to think clearly about whether information is flowing down the tree (from root to leaf) or up the tree (from leaf to root). It looks like the `node_data` argument to `root_to_leaf_helper` is initialized at the top of the tree, the root, and then passed down through each node via recursive calls. That's fine, but as far as I can tell, it's never changed on the way down the tree. It's just passed along untouched. Therefore the first check, for `node_data.num_found`, will always be false.

Even worse, since `node_data` is always the same (`(0, False)`) on the way down the tree, the following line that tries to add the current node's value to a running sum:

```
new_running_sum = node.val + node_data.running_sum
```

will always be adding `node.val` to 0, since `node_data.running_sum` is always 0.

Hopefully this is clear, I realize that it's a little difficult to explain.

But trying to think very clearly about information flowing down the tree (in the arguments to recursive calls) vs information flowing up the tree (in the return value from the recursive calls) will make this a little bit more clear.

Answer (score -1):

You can keep a running list of the path as part of the signature of the recursive function/method, and call the function/method on both the right and left nodes using a generator. The generator will enable you to find the paths extending from the starting nodes. For simplicity, I have implemented the solution as a class method:

```
class Tree:
  def __init__(self, *args):
    self.__dict__ = dict(zip(['value', 'left', 'right'], args))
  def get_sums(self, current = []):
    if self.left is None:
      yield current + [self.value]
    else:
      yield from self.left.get_sums(current+[self.value])
    if self.right is None:
      yield current+[self.value]
    else:
      yield from self.right.get_sums(current+[self.value])

tree = Tree(4, Tree(10, Tree(4, Tree(7, None, None), Tree(6, None, None)), Tree(12, None, None)), Tree(5, Tree(6, None, Tree(11, None, None)), None))
paths = list(tree.get_sums())
new_paths = [a for i, a in enumerate(paths) if a not in paths[:i]]
final_path = [i for i in paths if sum(i) == 15]
```

Output:

```
[[4, 5, 6]]
```

Comment: Thanks! I actually have a solution from the workbook I'm working out of - more curious about what went wrong in my approach and what to look out for in future.